# Windows Form: Microsoft Skin

Tags: c#, windows

Atualmente, estou vendo vários programas da Microsoft e de outras pessoas com esse visual:

[image: img]

[image: img]

Queria saber se é uma *skin* gratuita e qual o *link* dela.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Na verdade estamos falando aqui do [WPF](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms742119(v=vs.110).aspx). Seria um "Windows Form com vitaminas".

Não apenas a "skin" pode ser modificada, mas o tema todo. [Existe um projeto na Codeplex dedicado a esta customização, o WPF Toolkit](http://wpf.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=WPF%20Themes).

Ainda, [há este artigo no CodeProject mostrando o que é possível fazer, com exemplos implementados](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/22575/WPF-Themes-and-Skins-Engine). Também [há este outro artigo que ensina o passo-a-passo](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19782/Creating-a-Skinned-User-Interface-in-WPF).